# Обтекание текстом фигуры svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Есть у меня треугольник в `SVG`.Я не знаю как сделать, чтобы его обтекал текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.svg {
  width: 70%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  float: left;
}

.about-me-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 400px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid about-me-container">
  <svg class="svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(100,66,255);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(144,18,254);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="90, 0 1100,360 90,740" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
  <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="55" font-family="Comfortaa" x="400" y="370">Про Меня</text>
</svg>
  <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur cumque vel officia, dolorem et repellendus rerum ad totam laborum nobis quidem molestiae repellat vero voluptates sapiente modi ducimus, explicabo! Quod!</span>
</div>
```